# Copy either/or cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook with one page being the "data key" and all of the information flows through to the rest of the pages.  On certain information I need to take cell 1 or if it is blank take cell 2.

I have tried modifying IF and OR functions but they keep failing due to requiring a true/false or statistical analysis.

Is this possible or do I have to have a cell 3 on page 1 to determine the information to copy through?

Comment: An example of your workbook structure would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping me.  My workbook is a series of reports with a set of repetitive information that the client does not want to enter each time.  I have set up page one as my data set and am filtering the information throughout the workbook into the individual formulas and locations.  However I have these two data pieces that are an either/or but are not numerical.  Frankly they are names and the client refuses to set up an "individual" vs "business" form template and I cannot figure out how to pull name or business name.  It must be simple but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(isblank(cell1),cell2,cell1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the many true/false responses I have attempted to manipulate into what I need.

Comment: Do you have some sample/pretend data you could share if you still need help?